# Problems with caret: R

Tags: r, classification, text-classification, r-caret

**My code is below:**

```
library('RMySQL')
library('DMwR')
library('tm')
library('Snowball')
library('SnowballC')



rt_outlier <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT *,tweet_text from outlier_info,tweets where outlier_info.tweet_id=tweets.tweet_id limit 500")

rt_not_outlier <- dbGetQuery(con,"Select *, tweet_text from not_outlier_info,tweets where not_outlier_info.tweet_id=tweets.tweet_id limit 500");

dbDisconnect(con)

all_tweets = rbind(rt_outlier,rt_not_outlier)
all_tweets[,"tweet_text"] <- iconv(all_tweets[,"tweet_text"], to = "utf-8")

corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(all_tweets[,"tweet_text"]))
corpus = tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,removeWords,stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,removeNumbers)
mydata.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf, minWordLength=2, findFreqTerms=5))


dataframe <- as.data.frame(inspect(mydata.dtm))

d=as.data.frame(t(dataframe))

classData = c(rep(0,500),rep(1,500))
classData = as.factor(classData)

library('caret')
ctrl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3,)
set.seed(2)
mymodel <- train(d, classData,trControl=ctrl,method="J48",model=FALSE)
```

Basically, what is happening here is that I keep getting the error and warnings:

```
Error in train.default(d, classData, method = "J48", model = FALSE) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In train.default(d, classData, method = "J48", model = FALSE) :
  Models using Weka will not work with parallel processing with multicore/doMC
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
3: In train.default(d, classData, method = "J48", model = FALSE) :
  missing values found in aggregated results
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also note I'm using model=FALSE in training to conserve memory, as this has been a problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the message:

"`Models using Weka will not work with parallel processing with multicore/doMC`"?

Try running sequentially.

Even better, use `C5.0` in parallel. `J48` is not a great implementation of `C4.5`, especially when it comes to splitting categorical predictors.

Max

Comment: That is a warning, I tried w/o multicore and still had the same error: Error in train.default(d, classData, method = "J48", model = FALSE) : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined